# Firebase Push Notification Error - Entity not found

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification

I am having issues with firebase push notification. I keep getting this error, but I am using the correct push token passed by my app. Using nodejs with firebase admin.

This is my code:

```
console.log("the tokens", token)
    const message = {

        token: token,
        notification: {
            "title": msgTitle,
            "body": msgBody
        },
        data: {
            "action": action,
            "unique_id": uniqueId
        }
    }
    console.log("This is the message ", message)

    fbMsging.send(message)
        .then((response) => {
            // Response is a message ID string.
            console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        });
```

This is the error:

```
This is the message  {
  token: 'dxxxxxx_HM',
  notification: { title: 'Test Group Title', body: 'Test Group Bodyyyyyy' },
  data: { action: 'New_Card', unique_id: '1' }
}
Error sending message: FirebaseMessagingError: Requested entity was not found.
    at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\Users\lior\Desktop\bridged\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\Users\lior\Desktop\bridged\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:88:28)
    at new FirebaseMessagingError (C:\Users\lior\Desktop\bridged\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:254:16)
    at Function.FirebaseMessagingError.fromServerError (C:\Users\lior\Desktop\bridged\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:287:16)
    at Object.createFirebaseError (C:\Users\lior\Desktop\bridged\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\messaging\messaging-errors.js:34:47)
    at C:\Users\lior\Desktop\bridged\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\messaging\messaging-api-request.js:76:42
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  errorInfo: {
    code: 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered',
    message: 'Requested entity was not found.'
  },
  codePrefix: 'messaging'
}
```

However, I do always get this error first before the one above keeps showing up:

```
This is the message  {
  token: 'd6xxxxZZx',
  notification: { title: 'Test Group Title', body: 'Test Group Bodyyyyyy' },
  data: { action: 'New_Match', unique_id: '1' }
}
Error sending message: FirebaseMessagingError: Request contains an invalid argument.
    at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\Users\lior\Desktop\bridged\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\Users\lior\Desktop\bridged\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:88:28)
    at new FirebaseMessagingError (C:\Users\lior\Desktop\bridged\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:254:16)
    at Function.FirebaseMessagingError.fromServerError (C:\Users\lior\Desktop\bridged\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:287:16)
    at Object.createFirebaseError (C:\Users\lior\Desktop\bridged\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\messaging\messaging-errors.js:34:47)
    at C:\Users\lior\Desktop\bridged\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\messaging\messaging-api-request.js:76:42
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  errorInfo: {
    code: 'messaging/invalid-argument',
    message: 'Request contains an invalid argument.'
  },
  codePrefix: 'messaging'
}
Push failed.
GET /test_notify?push_token=d6oVIhuoiEpUosXn9U4SnW:APA91bFFER9PuZQJY8bESGAtKpo5PjSd1dIyVqucElrZiEbLkEkFubsPPb4AD-thnUVTa719f_dhlRp1Jl7sGdMwuKihaCfLCacWUfpoU2ovNP5DnV170EMNWQFd4IkrJfE5BLGhdZZx&unique_id=1&action=New_Match 200 407.818 ms - 3
```